# jQuery not working in a free downloaded template

Tags: jquery, html

ok heres my problem, ive downloaded a template and inserted jQuery in it. it does not work. But when I tested in on a different project, its working. heres the partial code in my project,

```
<head>
<title>School Website</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/TableCSSCode.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mootools-release-1.11.js"></script>
<script src="js/dropDownMenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#flip").click(function(){
            $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php include_once'config/connect.php';// database connection...?>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="top">
                <div class="logo"><a href="http://all-free-download.com/free-website-templates/"><span>SCHOOL</span> NAME</a></div>
                    <ul class="login">
                        <li class="left">&nbsp;</li>
                        <li>Hello Parents!</li>
                        <li>|</li>
                        <li>Login</li>
                        <li>|</li>
                        <li><a href="http://all-free-download.com/free-website-templates/">Register</a></li>
                    </ul>
  <div id="flip">
    <h1>hello world</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="panel">
    <h1>hello world</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ive tested it on the 2 hello worlds at the last part of the program. Is there anything wrong in my codes? thanks alot for the help.
Im using mozilla firefox 27.0.1

Comment: might be because of mootools try `jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#flip").click(function () {
        $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
    });
});`

Comment: JS frameworks don't typically play nice together - MooTools and Jquery, why both?

Comment: Don't forget to put jQuery before any jQuery scripts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there is a conflict between `Mootools` and `jQuery` since they're both using `$`, try to put your code inside a closure:

```
// Disable the $ global alias completely
jQuery.noConflict();

(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#flip").click(function(){
            $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Also, `slideDown` only works for hidden element so you need to hide the `#panel` first by css or jQuery

```
#panel {
    display: none;
}
```

or:

```
$('#panel').hide();
```

Final code should looks like:

```
// Disable the $ global alias completely
jQuery.noConflict();

(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#panel").hide();

        $("#flip").click(function(){
            $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks alot sir, this really helps. This was my first time using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

1. There might be a conflict between mootools and jQuery
2. If the element is already visible the slide down will not work so try with slideToggle() which will toggle the visibility

Try

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#flip").click(function () {
        $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```